# Using two values for 'Virtual Directory' in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, virtual-directory

I am using two URLs (say `url/internal`, `url/vendor`) for my application which has different authentication (one has AD authentication & the other has application login).

I have created two application under the default website in IIS - each of which is mapped to *same* root folder.

The issue i'm facing is when i login with `url/vendor` (which is using application login) and navigate to other pages from home page, the URL gets updated to `url/internal` and it subsequently asks for AD authentication.

Since the Virtual Directory in web.config is "internal" if i create different root folder for `url/vendor` and Virtual Directory as "Vendor" this issue is resolved.

But i want to use only one root folder.

**Question**: how can i achieve two values of VirtualDirectory in same web.config for two sites of application.

Comment: It is somewhat not clear what you are asking. Can your share the web.config file with the URLs and how are  you using those URLs?

Comment: I have modified the details.